# Idiom to execute expression of type unit iff condition is true

Tags: f#, idioms, unit-type

I find myself doing this occasionally:

```
if some_condition then 
    expr 
else
    ()
```

Is there a nicer way to do this? It seems there should be a one-liner. (Running it all into one line doesn't count. By "one-liner" I mean "something which in one line indicates more clearly my intentions.")

Comment: I don't understand the question... If the type of `expr` is `unit`, then the `else` is entirely optional to begin with

Comment: Ah, man. I didn't know that! You should make that an answer, I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As demonstrated (rather poorly) in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233231.aspx), if the final expression in the `if` has type `unit` then the `else` is optional. Thus your code can simply become:

```
if some_condition then expr
```